# c# gridview onrowupdating event page does not render

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

I am having an issue. I have a page that has a `Gridview` with *edit/update/cancel* edit on it.

The page works/renders until I add the **OnRowUpdating="UpdateRow"** to the `Gridview`.  Then the page does not render at all.
In Debugging it does not even get to the page load events.  When I take this property out of the Gridview (*without touching any code behind code*) the page renders.  I have been googling and can not find anything similar.  I can find if it does not fire/does not work but nothing about page not rendering.

My code is below:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None"
        AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
        Width="100%" 
        OnRowEditing="EditRow" 
        OnRowUpdating="UpdateRow"
        OnRowCancelingEdit="CancelEditRow" 
        DataKeyNames="OnCallID"             
        AllowPaging="true"
        PageSize="50" 
        OnPageIndexChanging="ChangePage"            
        OnRowDataBound="gvVehicle_OnRowDataBound"             
    >

        <Columns>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-Width="25px">

                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkEdit" runat="server" Text="Edit" CommandName="Edit" />
                </ItemTemplate>

                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkUpdate" runat="server" Text="Update" CommandName="Update" />
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CommandName="Cancel" />
                </EditItemTemplate>

            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="OnCallID" DataField="OnCallID" ReadOnly="true" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-Width="25px" Visible="false" />


            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="OnCallID" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-Width="600px" Visible="false" >
                <ItemTemplate><%# Eval("OnCallID")%></ItemTemplate>

                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="HDNOnCallID" runat="server" Visible="true" Text='<%# Eval("OnCallID")%>' />
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>


            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Team Member Name" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-Width="600px" >
                <ItemTemplate><%# Eval("TeamMemberName")%></ItemTemplate>

                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="LBLUserIDLST" runat="server" Visible="true" Text='<%# Eval("TeamMemberName")%>' />

                    <!--<asp:ListBox ID="UserIDLST"  runat="server" SelectionMode="Single" Visible="true" Width="100" Rows="1"></asp:ListBox>  -->
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="On Call Start Date" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-Width="600px" >
                <ItemTemplate><%# Eval("OnCallStartDate")%></ItemTemplate>

                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="StartDateEditUpdate" runat="server" MaxLength="10" name="StartDateEditUpdate" Width="70" Text='<%# Eval("OnCallStartDate")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:Image id="StartDateEditUpdateCalImg" runat="server" ImageUrl="../Images/CalendarImg.png" ImageAlign="Bottom" />

                    <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="extendStartDateEditUpdate" runat="server" CssClass="datePicker" PopupPosition="TopLeft" 
                        TargetControlID="StartDateEditUpdate" Format="MM/dd/yyyy" PopupButtonID="StartDateEditUpdateCalImg">
                    </ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender>

                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="validateStartDateEditUpdate"
                        ControlToValidate="StartDateEditUpdate"
                        Text="You must Type Something in for Start Date!"
                        runat="server" 
                        Enabled="true"
                        CssClass="validatorErrorDisplay"                
                        />

                </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="On Call Start Time" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-Width="600px" >
                <ItemTemplate><%# Eval("OnCallStartTime")%></ItemTemplate>

                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="StartTimeEditUpdate" runat="server" MaxLength="10" Width="100" Text='<%# Eval("OnCallStartTime")%>'></asp:TextBox>

                     <ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditExtender ID="MaskedEditorStartTimeEditUpdate" runat="server"
                        TargetControlID="StartTimeEditUpdate" 
                        Mask="99:99"
                        MessageValidatorTip="true" 
                        OnFocusCssClass="MaskedEditFocus" 
                        OnInvalidCssClass="MaskedEditError"
                        MaskType="Time" 
                        InputDirection="LeftToRight" 
                        ErrorTooltipEnabled="True" 
                        AcceptAMPM="true" 
                        AutoComplete="true"                
                        />

                        <ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditValidator ID="MaskedEditorValidatorStartTimeEditUpdate" runat="server"
                            ControlExtender="MaskedEditorStartTimeEditUpdate"
                            ControlToValidate="StartTimeEditUpdate" 
                            IsValidEmpty="true" 
                            AcceptAMPM = "true"                                        
                            InvalidValueMessage="This is not a valid time2"                                        
                            InvalidValueBlurredMessage="This is not a valid time" 
                            Enabled="true"                    
                            TooltipMessage="Must be in Time format HH:MM AM/PM" 
                            ValidationExpression="(0[1-9]|1[0-2]):([0-5][0-9]) (AM|PM|am|pm)"
                         />

                </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="On Call End Date" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-Width="600px" >
                <ItemTemplate><%# Eval("OnCallEndDate")%></ItemTemplate>

                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="EndDateEditUpdate" runat="server" MaxLength="10" name="EndDateEditUpdate" Width="70" Text='<%# Eval("OnCallEndDate")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:Image id="EndDateEditUpdateCalImg" runat="server" ImageUrl="../Images/CalendarImg.png" ImageAlign="Bottom" />
                    <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="extendEditUpdate"  runat="server" CssClass="datePicker" PopupPosition="TopLeft" 
                        TargetControlID="EndDateEditUpdate" Format="MM/dd/yyyy" PopupButtonID="EndDateEditUpdateCalImg">
                    </ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender>


                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="validateEndDateEditUpdate"
                        ControlToValidate="EndDateEditUpdate"
                        Text="You must Type Something in for End Date!"
                        runat="server" 
                        Enabled="true" 
                        CssClass="validatorErrorDisplay"
                        />

                    <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareStartDateEndDateEditUpdateValidator" Operator="GreaterThanEqual" Type="Date"
                        ControlToValidate="EndDateEditUpdate" ControlToCompare="StartDateEditUpdate"
                        ErrorMessage="End Date must be greater then Start Date!" runat="server" BackColor="Red" ForeColor="White"  />
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="On Call End Time" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-Width="600px" >
                <ItemTemplate><%# Eval("OnCallEndTime")%></ItemTemplate>

                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="EndTimeEditUpdate" runat="server" MaxLength="10" Width="100" Text='<%# Eval("OnCallEndTime")%>'></asp:TextBox>

                    <ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditExtender ID="MaskedEditorEndTimeEditUpdate" runat="server"
                        TargetControlID="EndTimeEditUpdate" 
                        Mask="99:99"
                        MessageValidatorTip="true" 
                        OnFocusCssClass="MaskedEditFocus" 
                        OnInvalidCssClass="MaskedEditError"
                        MaskType="Time" 
                        InputDirection="LeftToRight" 
                        ErrorTooltipEnabled="True" 
                        AcceptAMPM="true" 
                        AutoComplete="true"                
                        />

                    <ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditValidator ID="MaskedEditorValidatorEndTimeEditUpdate" runat="server"
                        ControlExtender="MaskedEditorEndTimeEditUpdate"
                        ControlToValidate="EndTimeEditUpdate" 
                        IsValidEmpty="true" 
                        AcceptAMPM = "true"                                        
                        InvalidValueMessage="This is not a valid time2"                                        
                        InvalidValueBlurredMessage="This is not a valid time" 
                        Enabled="true"                                        
                        TooltipMessage="Must be in Time format HH:MM AM/PM" 
                        ValidationExpression="(0[1-9]|1[0-2]):([0-5][0-9]) (AM|PM|am|pm)"
                        />
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>



        </Columns>

        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#efefef" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#F37721" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#F37721" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />

    </asp:GridView>


     protected void EditRow(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        // this enables/disables the add new row validation
        EnableDisableValidationsAndButtons(false);

        GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        this.PopulateData();

    }

    protected void CancelEditRow(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
    {
        // this enables/disables the add new row validation
        EnableDisableValidationsAndButtons(true);

        GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
        this.PopulateData();
    }

    protected void UpdateRow(object sender, GridViewUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {

        //GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)GridView1.Rows[e.NewEditIndex];
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)GridView1.Rows[GridView1.EditIndex];


        Label txtOnCallID = (Label)row.FindControl("HDNOnCallID");
        String OnCallID = txtOnCallID.Text.ToString();

        TextBox txtBoxStartDate = (TextBox)row.FindControl("StartDate");
        String StartDate = txtBoxStartDate.Text.ToString();

        TextBox txtBoxStartTime = (TextBox)row.FindControl("StartTime");
        String StartTime = txtBoxStartTime.Text.ToString();

        TextBox txtBoxEndDate = (TextBox)row.FindControl("EndDate");
        String EndDate = txtBoxStartDate.Text.ToString();

        TextBox txtBoxEndTime = (TextBox)row.FindControl("EndTime");
        String EndTime = txtBoxEndTime.Text.ToString();

        // do update stuff here
         SQL CODE HERE

        // run update
        //new DatabaseConnection().RSExecute(sCommand);

        lblMessage.Text = "Record successfully Updated!";

        GridView1.EditIndex = -1;

        //this.PopulateData();

        // doing a redirect here for the full URL because if you refresh page it adds the record duplicate times
        // also some of the form fields are still filled out, this removes them as well
        Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the signature of the function as below and check. You are binding function with GridViewUpdatedEventArgs instead of GridViewUpdateEventArgs

```
protected void UpdateRow(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
}
```

Comment: That seems to have worked. Stupid mistake on my part.

Not sure why this cause the page to not render at ALL (it wouldn't even get to the page load when debugging)??


Still testing but at least the page is rendering now and I am getting to the function when I click "update".

THANKS